# backbone.js - Overridden parse() does not set model attributes

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model which links to two sub-models like so:

```
var SubModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        headline: null,
        image_url: null,
        url: null
    }
});

var MainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        subModelA: null,
        subModelB: null,
        title: null
    },

    urlRoot: function() {
        if (this.isNew()) {
            return '/mainmodel/new';
        }
        return '/mainmodel';
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    },

    parse: function(data) {
        var response = {};
        response.subModelA = new SubModel(data.subModelA);
        response.subModelB = new SubModel(data.subModelB);
        response.title = data.title;
        return response;
    }
});
```

The issue I'm currently having is that calling `var mainModelInstance = new MainModel()` does correctly fetch from `/mainmodel/new` but `mainModelInstance.attributes` is always a blank object `{}`.

```
var mainModelInstance = new MainModel();
mainModelInstance.attributes; // Returns {}
```

Here is a sample of the server's response to `/mainmodel/new`:

```
{
    "title": "Politics",
    "subModelA": {
        "headline": "Investigators: Iran tried to smuggle suicide belts, missiles by boat into Yemen",
        "url": "http://dailycaller.com/2013/02/09/yemen-minister-says-weapons-came-from-iran/",
        "image_url": "http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/54c7d52e1a384db489ab9ea568afddb0-e1360455589316.jpg"
    },
    "subModelB": {
        "headline": "Review: Who needs Windows RT? Acer's Iconia W510 runs the real thing",
        "url": "http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/02/review-who-needs-windows-rt-acers-iconia-w510-runs-the-real-thing/",
        "image_url": "http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/w510-main-640x388.jpg"
    }
}
```

It seems as though the model's attributes are not being updated via `parse`.  Why aren't the model's attributes being updated?

Comment: Not sure the exact answer to your question, but 2 quick notes: be careful that model instance properties like MainModel's `subModelA` and `subModelB` are NOT the same thing as model data attributes, so trying to establish them via parse is NOT going to set them directly as instance properties, just into the attributes hash. Also, your code is quite odd in terms of REST conventions. You should be creating new models via model.save, not fetch and via POST not GET.

Comment: so far I guess, all you need to return json from parse() method. do not make any instances there.

Comment: @PeterLyons this isn't a typical REST scenario.  There isn't an initial state for the `MainModel` that is populated by defaults and there is no equivalent CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE scenarios.  There will be a custom method for this model which effectively records a choice between `subModelA` or `subModelB`.  `MainModel` represents a 'matchup' of sorts.

Comment: @MikeSukmanowsky Perhaps you could help us by explaining *what* you're trying to accomplish rather than how? What do you mean by choice? Also, @HungryCoder is right - ```parse``` is the wrong place to be doing model instantiation. It's job is simply to take a json object and update model attributes. You can see how it's used internally here: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-53

Comment: @JonJaques sure thing. Think of it as a voting system between `subModelA` and `subModelB`.  Server is responsible for generating a matchup (which has a title and two sub models).  The view displays the two sub models and a user can vote on one model or the other.

Comment: You may just be checking the attributes before the asynchronous request is complete.  Try `this.fetch({success:function(model){ console.log(model.attributes); });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code might as well be working, but you are not testing it correctly

You are calling `this.fetch` in yout initialize method.
calling `model.fetch` is an asynchronous call and when you are trying to evaluate `mainModelInstance.attributes`, the http request call is not yet completed.

You should test this with:

```
var mainModelInstance = new MainModel();
mainModelInstance.on('change', function() {
  console.log(mainModelInstance.toJSON());
});
```

or even better, dont auto fetch on `initialize` (its not a best practice anyway)
and use the jQuery promise pattern:

```
var mainModelInstance = new MainModel();
mainModelInstance.fetch().done(function () {
  console.log(mainModelInstance.toJSON());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a work in progress answer, feel free to discuss in the comments.

I would change your `MainModel` definition like so:

```
subModelA: new SubModelA(),
subModelB: new SubModelB(),
parse: function(data){
   this.subModelA.set(data.subModelA);
   this.subModelB.set(data.subModelB);
   return data;  // we keep two copies of the data, in mainModel and submodels.
}
```

So assuming your server responds exactly like in your answer

```
var model = new MainModel();
model.get('title'); // Politics
model.subModelA.get('headline'); // Investigators: Iran tr...
```

Then, you may have to override the save method depending on how you wish to persist things back to the server — this might work.

```
save: function(key, val, options) {
  this.set({
    subModelA: this.subModelA.toJSON(),
    subModelB: this.subModelB.toJSON()
  });
  Backbone.Model.prototype.save.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Of course you may find yourself overriding other methods too like ```update```. So then that begs the question, do you need multiple models?

Comment: I'm definitely considering scraping the submodel.  Biggest benefit was breaking up the view templates but it may be more harm than it's worth.  Thanks for the answer! Turns out my parse implementation was working all along but since `fetch()` is async, I was jumping the gun too early on expecting `model.attributes` to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

First, default attributes values must be put into the `defaults` option, like so:

```
var SubModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    headline: null,
    image_url: null,
    url: null
  }
});
```

Then, you'll have value to save to the server when creating a new instance. That will also fill up your `mainModelInstance.attributes` hash.

For the parsing problem, have you logged (`console.log`) in what you get back from the server?

Comment: I have and the response is valid https://gist.github.com/msukmanowsky/a41d8502332df0f02803

Comment: Yeah.. I don't have anything specific to add, but made a jsBin here. You beat me to the answer :) Override `sync` to work as a demo.  http://jsbin.com/ayaxey/1/edit

Comment: This is incorrect. the default attributes are optional and are used only to set the initial value. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults

Comment: @UziKilon you're right, can't believe I missed such a simple error!